# Calculating multiple descriptive statistics within one dataset in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, grouping, average

I have a dataset containing information about companies and their employees (age/gender etc). Currently each company employee is listed on a new row. What I want is to describe the company in terms of employee age average/std dev, gender average etc. Basicly go from multiple rows per company to 1 row per company containing these descriptive statistics.

What I have so far is this:

```
Sub mergecompany()

Dim Currentline As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim Agestart As Integer


For i = 2 To 30
j = 0
Currentline = (Cells(i, 1))
    If Currentline = 0 Then Exit For

        Do While Currentline = (Cells(i + j, 1))
            a = Val(Cells(i + j, 5))
            j = j + 1
            Cells(i, 20) = (Cells(i, 20) + a)
            Loop

Next i
End Sub
```

This gets me the correct sums of ages once per each group (the first row of each company) but also a lot of fluff, as you can see below
[image: example data]
How could I best go about removing the extra data? I'm guessing since I also want to calculate means/stddevs I'll have to keep count of the entries per group via use of arrays or a counter? Maybe use some sort of Entirerow.delete? Or not use VBA at all?

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider creating a Pivot Table (non-VBA route) which can help you build this kind of summary.

If you search for Pivot Table on google then several links will come up like one below:
http://www.contextures.com/CreatePivotTable_2007.html

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)?

Comment: Pivot table, as my predecessor said, or add-in Analysis ToolPack, or just using excel formulas. There is no need to rely of VBA here, as Excel is the tool made just for this kind of calculations (though is mostly used for arranging tables and binding them with vlookup)/

Comment: @Ralph I have very clearly written "If you search for Pivot Table on google then several links will come up like one below" and should be sufficient. I agree that links may not work but I do hope this one stays around.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that.. Pivot tables and some simple filtering did the job! No need at all to reinvent the wheel.. Thanks a bunch!